# How to remove the curly braces and string from JSON file using Perl

Tags: perl

```
{
    "ticket": {
    {
       "id":"01",
       "language": "Java",
       "edition": "third",
       "author": "Herbert Schildt"
    },
    {
       "id":"07",
       "language": "C++",
       "edition": "second"
       "author": "E.Balagurusamy"
    }
}
,
  "edition": "third",
   "author": "Herbert Schildt"
}
```

That's my JSON file. I want to remove from file starting part `{"ticket":`

and ending part  `,"edition": "third",  "author": "Herbert Schildt" }`.

Finally output I want like this:

```
 {
       "id":"01",
       "language": "Java",
       "edition": "third",
       "author": "Herbert Schildt"
    },
    {
       "id":"07",
       "language": "C++",
       "edition": "second"
       "author": "E.Balagurusamy"
    }
}
```

**Note**

Don't use regular expression, using only JSON Perl.

---

**update**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;

my($infile);
GetOptions('inFile=s' => \$infile);
my $json;
{
  local $/; 
  open my $fh, "<", "$infile";
  $json = <$fh>;
  close $fh;
}
my $text = decode_json($json);
```

I have done this up to decode, but how to remove the starting and ending parts?

Comment: Use [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS).

Comment: where is your code ? what have you tried?

Comment: Decode json, make changes, encode back to json.

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Do you want to select the part because syntax is broken in the outer parts? If so, provide some more details on or examples showing how the "good" part of the file is defined.

Comment: -1. Your input you posted isn't valid JSON, but I believe your actual input is valid JSON. Your desired output isn't valid JSON, but I believe you want valid JSON. Fix your sloppiness!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the syntax errors in your JSON file are by accident and fixing it with a comma and an array structure, this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $json = do {
  local $/;
  <DATA>;
};
my $data = decode_json($json);

my $data2 = $data->{ticket};
my $json2 = encode_json($data2);
print $json2, "\n";

__DATA__
{
  "ticket": [
    {
      "id":"01",
      "language": "Java",
      "edition": "third",
      "author": "Herbert Schildt"
    },
    {
      "id":"07",
      "language": "C++",
      "edition": "second",
      "author": "E.Balagurusamy"
    }
  ],
  "edition": "third",
  "author": "Herbert Schildt"
}
```

Prints out:

```
[{"language":"Java","edition":"third","author":"Herbert Schildt","id":"01"},{"language":"C++","edition":"second","author":"E.Balagurusamy","id":"07"}]
```